# Asymptotic property of Laplace transform

Tags: asymptotics, laplace-transform, laplace-method

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $s:=\inf \mathrm{supp}(\mu)=\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R} : \mu(x)>0\}$ is finite.

Then, I want to show following equation for $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

> \begin{align}
>   \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{\int e^{-(t+a)x} d\mu(x)}{\int e^{-tx} d\mu(x)} = e^{-as}.
> \end{align}

I've already showed following equation. 
\begin{align}
  \lim_{t\to\infty} \left( \int e^{-tx} d\mu(x)\right)^{1/t} = e^{-s}.
\end{align}
So, I thought this equation may be  applied to first equation, but I cannot do.

Thanks for your help.